# 22.04 kubuntu no sound

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, firefox

I have a 18.04 installed for a long time and the sound is OK. On the same computer I installed in double boot on another disk 22.04. But there is no sound neither with firefox nor with vlc. So it's not a sound card or cable hardware problem. Note: Firefox was malfunctioning on this 22.04 and I had to replace the snap install.